# go: cannot find GOROOT directory: C:\Go; C:\Go\bin

Tags: go

As title, I just install Go package in my laptop.
OS:Windows 7 Enterpreise SP1 (64bit)
Install path: `C:\go`

I've set "Environment Variables":

```
GOROOT 
Value = C:\GO;C:GO\bin
```

I made hello.go file and save it in `C:\go`

When I run `"go run hello.go" in CMD in C:\`, get error message as below:

```
go:cannot find cannot find GOROOT directory: C:\Go; C:\Go\bin
```

Comment: GOROOT should only be C:\Go. GOPATH should be your usual workspace (e.g. %HOME%\mycode\goprojects)

Answer (score 3):

`GOROOT` should be set to `d:/programs/go` if you installed it there.
`GOPATH` should be set to `d:/workspace/gopath` if you want it there.
Also, `d:\programs\go\bin` should preferably be added to PATH.

It seems like Go only accepts slash (/) and not backslash (\). But of course, for PATH, it should be backslash (\).

Answer (score 2):

The Golang article "[How to Write Go Code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH)" does mention:

The `GOPATH` environment variable specifies the location of your workspace. It is likely the only environment variable you'll need to set when developing Go code.
**Note that this must not be the same path as your Go installation.**

(and go installation is reference by `GOROOT`)

< To get started, create a workspace directory and set `GOPATH` accordingly.
Your workspace can be located wherever you like, but we'll use `$HOME/go` in this document.

```
mkdir %USERPROFILE%\go
set GOPATH=%USERPROFILE%\go
```

> For convenience, add the workspace's `bin` subdirectory to your `PATH`:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%GOPATH%\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not set GOROOT. Have a look at http://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html

Comment: very unhelpful answer. pls include some information specified in the link. FYI i am also facing the same probbblem and this link didn't help. if there is something in this link that can help but i missed, pls edit your answer and include that

Answer (score -2):

you will need to add (Edit the system environment variables) **GOPATH** & **GOROOT** as below. (Windows 10) And then **restart** the system

[image]