# go: cannot find GOROOT directory: c:\go

Tags: go, build

I unzipped [the Go distribution](https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.4.2.windows-amd64.zip) into `d:\dev\go`, added `d:\dev\go\bin` to my path, created a file `d:\projects\hello\hello.go` and set GOPATH to `d:\projects\hello`. Running `go build hello.go` tells me:

```
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: c:\go
```

Now [several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21899482/476074) [different](http://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html#tmp_3) [places](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really) strongly urge me *not* to set GOROOT, setting GOPATH should be everything that is needed.

Should I go against this recommendation or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Dave Cheney's [You don’t need to set GOROOT, really](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/14/you-dont-need-to-set-goroot-really) article:

> There are only two cases that where you may have to set a `$GOROOT` environment. These are both described in the [installation page](http://golang.org/doc/install#install) on the golang.org website. For completeness I will recap them here
>
> - You are a Linux, FreeBSD or OS X user using the the zip or tarball binary downloads from the golang.org website. These binaries have a `$GOROOT` value of `/usr/local/go` and recommend you unpack them into that location. If you choose not to do this, then you must set `$GOROOT` to the location you chose.
> - You are a Windows user using the zip binary download from the golang.org website. These binaries have a `$GOROOT` value of `C:\Go`. **If you place Go somewhere else on your system then you must set `$GOROOT` to the location you chose.**

(The rest of the article is a good read if you want to learn the history that has caused confusion over `GOROOT`, the summary is it's due to outdated instructions mostly from pre-Go1.)

So if you use a pre-built Go binary, *and* you want to put it somewhere other than where it "wants", then you need `GOROOT`. Otherwise (i.e. if you build Go from source, or if you put the binary distribution in the default location) you don't need or want to set `GOROOT` (the above article gives some reasons why not).

If you're unsure, the easiest way to get it "correct" is to first *not* set anything other `GOPATH`. Then run `go env` and see what it says; if that shows reasonable entries for `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` then you're done; only set variables to override that if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when compiling and when getting the compiler version, I solved the problem by deleting the system variable GOROOT and reassigning it. was c:\Go; became c:\Go    =)

Answer (score 0):

I set GOROOT to point to the content of that dir:

```
AUTHORS      PATENTS      api          favicon.ico  misc         src
CONTRIBUTORS README       bin          include      pkg          test
LICENSE      VERSION      doc          lib          robots.txt
```

That's the dir which containts src, bin, doc, lib, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Once Go lang is installed, GOROOT is the root directory of the installation.

When I exploded Go Lang binary in Windows C:\ directory, my GOROOT should be C:\go.
If Installed with Windows installer, it may be C:\Program Files\go (or C:\Program Files (x86)\go, for 64-bit packages)

```
 GOROOT = C:\go
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the cache problem.

For me, I reopen the MinGW (I installed go in msys2 by pacman), and it worked.