# go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/bin/go

Tags: go

Im trying to install a package but get the below problem even though my ROOT directory is set properly.

```
p@p-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ which go
/usr/bin/go
p@p-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ echo $GOROOT
/usr/bin/go
p@p-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ go get github.com/Sirupsen/logrus
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/bin/go
```

Comment: Do not set GOROOT.

Comment: Just like in [your other question a few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952719/go-installing-package-usr-bin-go-not-a-directory), this is wrong, and [the answer is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970390/what-should-be-the-values-of-gopath-and-goroot).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what should be the values of GOPATH and GOROOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970390/what-should-be-the-values-of-gopath-and-goroot)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [go: cannot find GOROOT directory: c:\go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094751/go-cannot-find-goroot-directory-c-go)

Answer (score 3):

If one issues `go env` then the following could be returned:

```
set GOPATH=C:\Users\user\go
set GOROOT=C:\tools\go
```

What is the [`GOPATH`](https://golang.org/doc/install)?

> Create your workspace directory, `%USERPROFILE%\go`. (If you'd like to
>   use a different directory, you will need to set the `GOPATH` environment
>   variable; see How to Write Go Code for details.)

What is the [`GOROOT`](https://golang.org/doc/install)?

> If you chose a directory other than c:\Go, you must set the GOROOT
>   environment variable to your chosen path.